# Getting error when open any order Exception occurred during order load in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2, admin-panel, order-grid, edit-order

I am facing issue when click on view order link in admin.

> Exception occurred during order load

How can I fix the issue? I am working on Magento 2.2.2

Comment: Can you please check logs?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it but nothing related to order. But it is working in production mode.

Comment: @VinodKumar did you got the solution. please refer i am facing same issue